# is it possible to read the text in a pdf file using perl?

Tags: perl

I want to parse the  text from a pdf file in perl without converting the pdf into any other format . Is it possible ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136990/how-can-i-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file-in-perl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can.

Take a look at the [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/) package.

You can use this module to pull the text out.

```
 my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($filename);
 my $pageone_tree = $pdf->getPageContentTree(1);
 print CAM::PDF::PageText->render($pageone_tree);
```

Comment: Deleted mine, yours is the better package.