# How do I extract text from a number of PDF files contained in subfolders?

Tags: perl, pdf, batch-file, indexing

I need to organise thousands of PDF files, badly named and organised. They are found within one main folder, but they are stored in a variety of subfolders and I cannot alter that folder structure.

My objective is to extract the text of all PDFs and append it to one large text file, which will be useful for later indexing. In my text file I would like to get in the text folder the PDF file path and at the end of each page `@@@@ End of page # 1 @@@@`.

The text document would start:

```
@@@@ PDF Filepath : $thefilepath @@@@
.... text ....
.... text ....
.... text ....
@@@@ End of page # 1 @@@@
.... text ....
.... text ....
@@@@ End of page # 2 @@@@
@@@ PDF Filepath : $thenextfilepath @@@@
.... text ....
....
....
```

Could anybody give me a hand for this?

Comment: what have you tried? what do you intend to use to extract the text from the pdf files? what problems you found? what is your programming question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I extract text from a PDF file in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136990/how-can-i-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file-in-perl)

Comment: What "page" mean to you? How I know that a page ends based on the contents of a PDF file?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way is simply to loop through the files, using the **readdir** builtin function to get the names of the subfolders and files.
For each file you extract the text using some Perl module or command-line utility (for example [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/), [Text::FromAny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aFromAny) or **pdftotext**) and append it to the output text file along with the PDF file path and page info.

Comment: Great suggestions, Snorri!  `CAM::PDF` includes `$doc->numPages()` and `$doc->getPageText($pagenum)` (where, e.g, `my $doc = CAM::PDF->new('test1.pdf');`) that can be used to create the aggregated text document.