# perl regex to remove space from OCR text imported from pdftotext

Tags: regex, perl, text, ocr, data-cleaning

Text mining issue: from section titles, figure captions and elsewhere, in many PDF files I am getting sentences like:

```
"T h e n as data we give the t r a j e c t o r i e s o f the particles between ..."
```

I guess this is an OCR issue with pdftotext.

I can remove spaces in gappy text only with a chained regexp sequence that first increases whitespace, but this relies on word boundaries *in the original OCR text* being at LEAST double spaced. e.g., here's a simple test:

```
$ perl -e '$t="The \ \ \ \   t h i n g   w r o n g    h e r e   is we have  a  gap  s.";  print "$t\n"; 
$t=~s/(\s{2,})/$1  /g;    print "$t\n"; 
$t=~s/(\w)\s?/$1/g;       print "$t\n"; 
$t=~s/\s+/ /g;            print "$t\n";'

The       t h i n g   w r o n g     h e r e   is we have  a  gap  s.
The         t h i n g     w r o n g      h e r e     is we have      a    gap    s.
The           t h i n g     w r o n g     h e r e     is   we    have      a    gap      s.  
The          thing    wrong    here    is  we  have     a   gap     s. 
The thing wrong here is we have a gap s.
```

the end sentence period "gap s." is deliberate, it should not close up.

Question 1. Is there a more elegant set of regex's to do this?

Question 2.  What the heck can be done with the single-spaced only OCR text dump?  I assume one can only solve this generally to clean up text of the form:
"T h e n as data we give the t r a j e c t o r i e s o f the particles between ..."
when the word boundaries are not clear using some heavy duty module that looks for dictionary words in a string of single letters.  Is there such a  module?  (I've searched but have not located one so far.)

Comment: You're trying to manipulate natural language with regexes. Difficult at best, and, in the space you're working in, likely impossible. Proceed with caution, here there be dragons...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136990/how-can-i-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file-in-perl

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/CAM-PDF-1.60/bin/getpdftext.pl

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem (that of too many spaces), you can easily solve it with `s/\s+/ /g`. As for the second problem, I'm uncertain if there's a library like that.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1 :**

- Any Regex based solution will not give you good solution for single space problem.

**Answer 2 :**

- For issue like, - "T h e n as data we give the t r a j e c t o r i e s o f the particles between"
- First you can remove all spaces from sentence and then use - [Word Segmentation Solution](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/How%20to%20Do%20Things%20with%20Words.ipynb) from [Norvig](http://norvig.com/)'s work.

**Example :**

```
from __future__ import division
from collections import Counter
import re, nltk

WORDS = nltk.corpus.abc.words()
COUNTS = Counter(WORDS)

def pdist(counter):
    "Make a probability distribution, given evidence from a Counter."
    N = sum(counter.values())
    return lambda x: counter[x]/N

P = pdist(COUNTS)

def Pwords(words):
    "Probability of words, assuming each word is independent of others."
    return product(P(w) for w in words)

def product(nums):
    "Multiply the numbers together.  (Like `sum`, but with multiplication.)"
    result = 1
    for x in nums:
        result *= x
    return result

def memo(f):
    "Memoize function f, whose args must all be hashable."
    cache = {}
    def fmemo(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = f(*args)
        return cache[args]
    fmemo.cache = cache
    return fmemo

def splits(text, start=0, L=20):
    "Return a list of all (first, rest) pairs; start <= len(first) <= L."
    return [(text[:i], text[i:]) 
            for i in range(start, min(len(text), L)+1)]

@memo
def segment(text):
    "Return a list of words that is the most probable segmentation of text."
    if not text: 
        return []
    else:
        candidates = ([first] + segment(rest) 
                      for (first, rest) in splits(text, 1))
        return max(candidates, key=Pwords)

text = "T h e n as data we give the t r a j e c t o r i e s o f the particles between"
text = text.replace(" ", "")
print segment(text)
# ['Then', 'as', 'data', 'we', 'give', 'the', 'trajectories', 'of', 'the', 'particles', 'between']
```

=> Best solution will be to find why you are getting spaces in **pdftotext** module. If there is an issue in pdftotext which you can't solve try to explore other libraries for OCR.