# How to compare 2 PDFs if they're the same in Perl?

Tags: perl, pdf, module, compare

We're just entering the planning phase for a small script using perl. We hope to use it to reduce storage use, by removing duplicated PDFs. These PDFs have different file names, but have exactly the same content. Is there an existing perl module that I can use to open PDFs, and check if 2 PDF files have exactly the same content? Thank you

Comment: Do they look the same or have the same content "byte by byte"?

Comment: If "have exactly the same content" means byte by byte, then [File::Compare](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Compare.html) may be worth look.

Comment: And this question deals with extracting text from a PDF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136990/how-can-i-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file-in-perl

Comment: File::Compare worked perfectly, thank you!